# How to fix a footer which was designed using flexbox

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox, frontend

I'm trying to clone the Google home page and I designed the footer using flexbox, but now I can't position it at the bottom of the page. How can I fix that or is there any other technique to tackle this problem.

Here is the screenshot and code of the page. I know it's messy and lack of design. First I just want to get the structure right.

[screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quLYo.png)

````
```html
<body>
    <div class="heading">
        <div></div>
        <div class="gmail">
            <p>Gmail</p>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <p>images</p>
        </div>
        <div class="gapps">
            <button></button>
        </div>
        <div class="dp">
            <p>dp</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="google-logo">
            <img
                src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
                alt="Google logo"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="search-bar">
            <input
                type="search"
                name="q"
                aria-label="Search through site content"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="search-buttons">
            <div class="search-button">
                <button>Google Search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="feeling-lucky">
                <button>I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="srilanka">
            <p>Sri Lanka</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="footer-bottom-left">
                <div class="about">
                    <p>About</p>
                </div>
                <div class="advertising">
                    <p>Advertising</p>
                </div>
                <div class="business">
                    <p>Business</p>
                </div>
                <div class="how-search-works">
                    <p>How Search Works</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-bottom-right">
                <div class="privacy">
                    <p>Privacy</p>
                </div>
                <div class="terms">
                    <p>Terms</p>
                </div>
                <div class="settings">
                    <p>Settings</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css

body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #222;
}

.heading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.gmail {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.images {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.gapps {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.dp {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.google-logo {
    padding-bottom: 3vh;
}

.search-bar {
    padding-bottom: 3vh;
}

.search-buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.feeling-lucky {
    padding-left: 2vh;
}

.footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer-bottom {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer-bottom-left {
    display: flex;
}

.srilanka {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.about {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.advertising {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.business {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.how-search-works {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.privacy {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.terms {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.settings {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-bottom-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-items: flex-end;
}


```
````

Comment: You should post your code, not just a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come on broh, add a lil bit of semantics there

```
<html>
    <head></head>
     <body>
          <header></header>
           <main></main>
           <footer class=“footer”></footer>
      </body>
```

It doesn’t matter if you use: flex, flow, grid
as those properties are defined with display. If you want to set your element at the bottom, we are talking about a position.

So you need to set its position

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to post your code as well, not just a screenshot.
btw you can use the following code on your footer and it will stick to the bottom of your page

```
    footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0
width: 100%
    }
```

Comment: I did that. but when I use this the right part gets separated and sticked to the normal flow.